# Select join statement is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make an output array from next statement:

I have 2 tables. In each table there is "material_code" which plays the main role. I want to select *material_code* from *table1* where it'is equal to *material_code* from *table2* and join them where *status* (from table2) is equal to *0*.

This is what I've got so far.

```
SELECT material_code FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON material_code WHERE status IS 0
```

Solution:

```
SELECT material_code FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.material_code = table2.material_code WHERE status = 0
```

Thank everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this one:

```
SELECT 
    material_code 
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table1.material_code = table2.material_code 
WHERE status = 0
```

Comment: Dunno why I haven't seen this comment. I've waste about 1 hour debugging and finding a solution by myself but anyway thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT material_code FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 USING (material_code) WHERE status = 0
```

If you use `LEFT JOIN`, you will get records that only exist in table1 and not in table2.  You also want to use `USING` not `ON` if the column name is the same in both tables (at least in MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE status IS 0
```

should be

```
WHERE status = 0
```

Only when for `null` it have to be `IS NULL`.

And you also missed the join condition (`ON table1.material_code = table2.material_code`)

Comment: Shouldn't we add also this statement `ON table1.material_code = table2.material_code`?

Comment: @Christos Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field 'status' in bot table, you can use an explicit table name before the field name to add a condition only on 'status' of table1 like :

```
WHERE table2.status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this SQL code. `INNER JOIN` is better in your case.

```
SELECT tb1.material_code 
FROM table1 as tb1 
INNER JOIN table2 as tb2 ON tb1.material_code=tb2.material_code 
WHERE tb2.status = 0
```